# Check for equal dates with an if function

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have an array of dates and want to check via an if else statement if the date in another colume is equal to the date in the array.

I tried it with this formula:

```
=IF($F$2:$M$14=A1;1;0)
```

Please also see the picture:
[image]

**PS.**: My version is `excel 2010`.

Comment: Why not a simple `=countif(F$2:$M$14,A1)`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thx for your answer! However, tried it in my sheet, but it does not work for some dates. The answer, why much more difficult, cause I propably want to change the two value statements of the if function later...

Comment: Which dates does it not work for? Hope you replaced `,` by `;`? As far as changing the two value statements of the if function later, you could use `countif` in the if statement :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Ok sorry my fault. Problem was to refresh the cells. It works perfectly!!! Btw how could I integrate this into a plain if statement?

Comment: `=IF(COUNTIF(F$2:$M$14,A1)=0,DOSOMETHING,DOSOMETHINGELSE)`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Please write this as an answer and I will except it!!!

Comment: `COUNTIF` is better but your logic isn't too far out - use this "array formula" and you also get a count of dates in the range that match A1 =SUM(IF($F$2:$M$14=A1;1;0)) - needs to be confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to find a match in your case would be to use the `COUNTIF()` function.

**Syntax**

```
COUNTIF(range, criteria)
```

For example

`=COUNTIF(F$2:$M$14,A1)`

As per your comment if you want to change `value statements` then you can use the same in an `IF` as well.

`=IF(COUNTIF(F$2:$M$14,A1)=0,DOSOMETHING,DOSOMETHINGELSE)`

Simply replace `DOSOMETHING` and `DOSOMETHINGELSE` with what you want in lieu of them.

**NOTE**: Replace `,` by `;` if you are using a different regional setting.